# Undefined index in php?

Tags: php, session, post

I am trying to get the value from a textbox in another page I created and the textbox is automatically set to 0 but it keeps on telling me that the index is undefined? but once you click the confirm button the value gets submitted but I want it to automatically set as 0 without having to click the button.

This is page1:

```
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['topscart']))
 {
 $_SESSION['topscart']=$_POST['topscart'];
 print"<script language=javascript>
window.location='ACCOUNT.php';
</script>";
 }
 ?>
```

This is page 2:

```
<td>No. of Female Tops Ordered: </td>
<td><center><?php 
print" ".$_SESSION['topscart'];
?>
</td>
```

Textbox Code in page 1:

```
No. of Female Tops in Your Cart: <input type="text" value="0" size="10" name="topscart" id="topscart" >
Total: <input text="text"  size="10" value="0" name="topstotal" id="topstotal" >
<input type ="submit" value="Confirm Order"></button>
<input type ="reset"  id="topsbutton2" name="topsbutton2" value="Cancel Order"></button>
</center>
```

Comment: on page 2 do you have session_start();? on page 1 do you have session_start();?

Comment: Yes, I have those both at the top.

Comment: You may have other codes that cause trouble. Like a session destroy or session unset

Comment: by "textbox", do you mean "checkbox" ?

Comment: please, provide more info about the form and how you send data

Comment: Nope, I don't have those in my code. The only problem I have is that I want the table in page 2 to set to 0 automatically without having to click the confirm button that I added. But I have no problems when the button is clicked. I already have the textbox set to 0.

Comment: No, what i'm really using is a textbox.

Comment: @DreamyNeutron Where is your textbox code?

Comment: @Miya G added the code.

Comment: @DreamyNeutron Have you defined method type on form while submitting data?

Comment: Yes, <form action=TOPS.php name=tops method=post> The only thing that I want is to set everything in the table to 0 unless they actually went and confirmed their orders(pressed the confirm order button) in page 1.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand the purpose but you must click the button to populate the $_POST variable.

If you must, set the value to 0 and automatically get it in $_POST then you need to use JS also - on page load fill-up the "topscart" with 0, and use .click() of the button.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['topscart']))
 {

 session_start();
 $_SESSION["topscart"] = $_POST['topscart'];
  print"<script language=javascript>
  window.location='ACCOUNT.php';
 </script>";

 }
 ?>
```

2nd page

```
<?php
  session_start();
 echo $_SESSION["topscart"];
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to default the session value to 0 unless it is set by the initial form? If that is the case then update the code on page 1 to:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['topscart']))
{
  $_SESSION['topscart']=$_POST['topscart'];
  print"<script language=javascript>
  window.location='ACCOUNT.php';
  </script>";
} else {
  $_SESSION['topscart'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This works but you need to visit the page first to set the values in the table to 0. Is there any other way to set the values in the table to 0 without actually going to the page?

Comment: What I mean by page is not going to page 1 but straight to page 2.

Comment: add in `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['topscart'])) $_SESSION['topscart'] = 0; ?>` to page 2 which will set the session variable to 0 if it hasn't already been set

Comment: The values that I keep on inputting on page 1 won't show up in page 2

Comment: On page 1 before `print"<script language=javascript>` try adding in `var_dump($_SESSION);exit();` so you can see if the session variable is being set before the redirect.

Comment: Try adding `echo session_id();` to each page under your `start_session()` and check that they both match up